# nginxadmin 1 upstream timed out cpanel

Tags: linux, nginx, cpanel, centos6

I have install nginxadmin on my freshly install cpanel vps. I get 504 timeout when I try to login into domain. Here are my log and configs.

Logs--------------------

2015/03/06 16:58:25 [error] 31665#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.225.179.242, server: lyntouch.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://149.210.164.212:8081/", host: "lyntouch.com"

Config -------------------------- nginx.conf

```
user  nobody;
# no need for more workers in the proxy mode
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20480;
events {
 worker_connections 5120; # increase for busier servers
 use epoll; # you should use epoll here for Linux kernels 2.6.x
}
http {
 server_name_in_redirect off;
 server_names_hash_max_size 10240;
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024;
 include    mime.types;
 default_type  application/octet-stream;
 server_tokens off;
# remove/commentout disable_symlinks if_not_owner;if you get Permission denied error
# disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
 sendfile on;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout  5;
 gzip on;
 gzip_vary on;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
 gzip_proxied any;
 gzip_http_version 1.0;
 gzip_min_length  1000;
 gzip_comp_level  6;
 gzip_buffers  16 8k;
# You can remove image/png image/x-icon image/gif image/jpeg if you have slow CPU
 gzip_types    text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/xml application/javascript application/xml+rss text/javascript application/atom+xml;
 ignore_invalid_headers on;
 client_header_timeout  3m;
 client_body_timeout 3m;
 send_timeout     3m;
 reset_timedout_connection on;
 connection_pool_size  256;
 client_header_buffer_size 256k;
 large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;
 client_max_body_size 200M; 
 client_body_buffer_size 128k;
 request_pool_size  32k;
 output_buffers   4 32k;
 postpone_output  1460;
 proxy_temp_path  /tmp/nginx_proxy/;
 proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:15m inactive=24h max_size=500m;
 client_body_in_file_only on;
 log_format bytes_log "$msec $bytes_sent .";
 log_format custom_microcache '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" nocache:$no_cache';
include "/etc/nginx/vhosts/*";
}
```

vhosts conf ----------------------------------

```
server {
          error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
          listen 149.210.164.212:80;
          listen [::]:80;
      server_name lyntouch.com www.lyntouch.com;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/lyntouch.com-bytes_log bytes_log;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/lyntouch.com combined;
          root /home/lyntouch/public_html;
          #location / {
          location ~*.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
          expires 1M;
          try_files $uri @backend;
          }
          location / {
      error_page 405 = @backend;
          add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
          proxy_pass http://149.210.164.212:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
          }
          location @backend {
          internal;
          proxy_pass http://149.210.164.212:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
          }
          location ~ .*\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
          proxy_pass http://149.210.164.212:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
          }
          location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
          }
        }
```

what could be causing it?

Here is httpd.conf virtual host part ------------------

```
# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED.  IF YOU NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE PLEASE USE THE INCLUDE FILES.

<VirtualHost 149.210.164.212:8081>
    ServerName lyntouch.com
    ServerAlias www.lyntouch.com
    DocumentRoot /home/lyntouch/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lyntouch.com
    UseCanonicalName Off

    ## User lyntouch # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled lyntouch

    # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache versions >= 2.4.
    # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacyExprParser in
    # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
    #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
    <IfModule mod_include.c>
        <Directory "/home/lyntouch/public_html">
            SSILegacyExprParser On
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup lyntouch lyntouch
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup lyntouch lyntouch
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid lyntouch lyntouch
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
        #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
        AssignUserID lyntouch lyntouch
    </IfModule>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/lyntouch/public_html/cgi-bin/




    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_4/lyntouch/lyntouch.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

As soon as I uninstall nginxadmin everything comes back to normal.

Comment: Not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

You will have update **proxy_read_timeout** value in your configuration file.